# Rails has_many relationship find name based on foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

```
class country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
end

class company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
end
```

In my view index for company I can show which country the company belongs to by showing the following:

```
<%= company.country_id %>
```

This will show me the id number it's associated with, but I can't seem to work out how to resolve this back to the country name which is country.name, everything I seem to try crashes rails, I don't think I'm approaching the problem the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= company.country.try(:name) %>
```

really ought to do what you want.

Edited as comment suggested.

Comment: Insert a try in this code in order to be silent (not raise an error) if a company has no country associated with: `<%= company.country.try(:name) %>`

Comment: May be you should put `@company = Company.includes(:country).find(params[:id])` in the controller action. As its a good practice to have these query/association related stuff in controller rather than in views.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using #try though. It is much better when you tell Rails to give you the filtered collection, that's what controllers are for.

In this case you'd have

```
    class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @companies = Company.where('country_id IS NOT NULL') #if using the relational db
        # or @companies = Company.all.select { |company| company.country.present? }
      end
    end
```

and in your view

```
    <% @companies.each do |company| %>
      <%= company.country.name %>
    <% end %>
```

**Update:**

Even better aproach is to create a named scope in your model for such things.

```
    class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
      #...
      scope :with_country, ->() { where('country_id IS NOT NULL') }  
    end
```

Now you can change your controller action

```
   def index
     @companies = Company.with_country
   end
```

This will make your code much more consistent and readable.